# OpenCV Get the closest contour to a point

Tags: c++, opencv

I just write a function to get the contour of the object which is closest to a point. I think is not that hard, but I dont know why I cant use `sqrt` in this function. and result I got is quite strange, not the one as supposed.

```
void FindContour(Mat a,Mat &image){
    Mat temp;  
    int x=0, y=0;
    int i;
    int largest=65535;
    a.copyTo(temp);  
    vector< vector<Point> > contours;  
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;  
    findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );  
    for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {  
         Moments moment = moments(contours[index]);
         double area = moment.m00;  
         int  a = moment.m10/area;  
         int  b = moment.m01/area;  
          i=std::sqrt((a-50)^2+(b-60)^2);  
           if (i<largest)
           {  x=a;
              y=b; 
              largest=i;
              cout<<"x"<<x<<"y"<<y<<"i"<<i<<"/n"; 
           }

    }    
       Point2i pt(x,y); 
       circle(image,pt,20,Scalar(0,255,0),2); 
    putText(image,"object",Point(x,y+30),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0),2);
}
```

Comment: In C++, `^` operator is not the exponentiation operator. It's for bit-wise xor. You need to write it as `(a-50)*(a-50)` to do square. There is also `std::pow` in the standard library, but don't use it for simple squares and cubes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i=std::sqrt((a-50)^2+(b-60)^2);
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Because `a`, `b` are defined as `int`s, the result `(a-50)^2+(b-60)^2` will also be `int`. This will make the program ambiguous to select which [`std::sqrt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) to use.

[image]

To work out, you can first cast it to `float` before calling this function. Like this:

```
i=std::sqrt((float) ((a-50)^2+(b-60)^2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cv::pointPolygonTest](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html) for computing point-polygon distance.